# CSS - input field and button to be of same width

Tags: css, button, input, flexbox, width

I made a simple example of my issue [here](https://codepen.io/pprunesquallor/pen/wXqgJd).

I want the button to be of the same width as the input field.
The only thing is, there's a padding-left of 1rem on the input field because I don't want the placeholder sticking directly to the left side of the field. 
I assume that has to do with the solution to this, but I'm stuck.

Help much appreciated!

```css
html {
  font-size: 12px;
}

.login-form {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column; 
  align-items: center;
  width: 20rem;
  padding: 1em;
  background-color: #F00;
}

.form-control {
  width: 100%;
  border: 0;
  padding-left: 1rem;
  margin-bottom: 1rem;      
  color: #000;
}

.btn-sub {
  width: 100%;
}
```

```html
<div class=container>
  <form class=login-form>
    <input class="form-control" placeholder="Enter your email">
    <button class="btn-sub">Subscribe</button>
  </form>
</div>
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Adjust the `box-sizing` of the children to `border-box`...

```
form.login-form * {
    box-sizing: border-box;
}
```

```css
html {
  font-size: 12px;
}

.login-form {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  align-items: center;
  width: 20rem;
  padding: 1em;
  background-color: #F00;
}

.form-control {
  width: 100%;
  border: 0;
  padding-left: 1rem;
  margin-bottom: 1rem;
  color: #000;
}

form.login-form * {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

.btn-sub {
  width: 100%;
}
```

```html
<div class=container>
  <form class=login-form>
    <input class="form-control" placeholder="Enter your email">
    <button class="btn-sub">Subscribe</button>
  </form>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Just add `*{box-sizing:border-box;}` to CSS

```css
*{box-sizing:border-box;}

html {
  font-size: 12px;
}

.login-form {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column; 
  align-items: center;
  width: 20rem;
  padding: 1em;
  background-color: #F00;
}

.form-control {
  width: 100%;
  border: 0;
  padding-left: 1rem;
  margin-bottom: 1rem;      
  color: #000;
}

.btn-sub {
  width: 100%;
}
```

```html
<div class=container>
  <form class=login-form>
    <input class="form-control" placeholder="Enter your email">
    <button class="btn-sub">Subscribe</button>
  </form>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Add `box-sizing: border-box;` css propertiy in `.form-control` class